# How send json in php with HttpURLConnection to read like 'php://input'?

Tags: php, android, json, http, android-asynctask

I try to read data from json send by HttpURLConnection.

Activity.

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
 String json = gson.toJson(cDati);

 if(FunzioniSalvataggio.getInstance(mContext).saveDataToSend(json,"InizioServizio_")) 
   new FunzioniInvio().execute(json);
```

AsyncTask.

```
 URL paginaURL = new URL("http:***");

 HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) paginaURL.openConnection();
 client.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
 client.setDoOutput(true);
 client.setDoInput(true);
 client.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
 client.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
 client.setRequestMethod("POST");

 client.connect();

 OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
 wr.write(json);
 wr.flush();

 InputStream risposta = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
 dati = mostroDati(risposta);
```

PHP.

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");  
$json = json_decode($postdata, true);
```

But when PHP page try to read it with "php://input", it not found data. How do it?

Comment: Seems to me you are missing quite a bit of code, here. What is `json` in this statement `wr.write(json);` ??

Comment: Json is a string that contains serialized list of my objects!

Comment: What does your PHP code look like? Are you getting any errors server side?

Comment: @Barns52 i edit a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used `OutputStreamWriter` but I have had success with the `DataOutputStream`.
Try this and encode your json string

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(json,"UTF-8"));
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

I have no problem with this code. But, I have heard some people have problems with the `wr.close();` statement.

I would suggest that you URL-encode the data you are sending. This can be important if some unusual characters are included in the data you send.

Comment: Yes, but it non works. Now I add on client.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json", "UTF-8"); and  it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line:

```
client.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
```

In my case (PHP 7.x) it was the culprit.